# R-Caret: How to access model-specific train control parameters

Tags: r, r-caret

I am curious about how to extract the default model settings from a caret trained model.  In my case I am using `ctree` to build a regression tree.

```
library(caret)
library(party)
data(trees)
# case 1: use ctree directly
ctree_train_control<-ctree_control()
ct<-ctree(Volume~.,trees,control=ctree_train_control)
# case 2: use ctree train method in caret
modFitCtree<-train(Volume~.,data=trees,method='ctree')
```

Suppose I want to know if the `ctree` training control parameter `testtype` used in `modFitCtree`  is "Bonferroni" or something else.  In case 1, I can manually inspect `ctree_train_control` to find the default settings.  If I had the caret model from case 2, is there a field somewhere to extract these model settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know how the model is fit, use `getModelInfo("ctree", regex = FALSE)[[1]]$fit` to see. In this case, the relevant lines are:

```
if(any(names(theDots) == "controls")) {
   theDots$controls@gtctrl@mincriterion 

In other words, if you don't specify anything, only mincriterion is changed. Note that it is intercepting the controls argument so you can still pass that in and it will leave everything but mincriterion alone. 

After you fit the model, you have access to whatever is saved. In this case:


> slotNames(modFitCtree$finalModel)
 [1] "data"                "responses"           "cond_distr_response"
 [4] "predict_response"    "prediction_weights"  "get_where"          
 [7] "update"              "tree"                "where"              
[10] "weights"
```